# maxlength not working if value is set from js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maxlength

I am having the following HTML block in my page.

```
<input type="text" id="fillingInput"/>
<input type="text" id="filledInput" maxlength="5"/>
<input type="button" onclick="$('#filledInput').val($('#fillingInput').val());"/>
```

when the button is clicked, the value of ***fillingInput*** is set as value for **filledInput**.
But the maxlength is not considered while setting value like this.
Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try `slice`:

```
<input type="button"
  onclick="$('#filledInput').val($('#fillingInput').val().slice(0,5));"/>
```

Comment: i want the fillingInput as common input for multiple filledInputs which are having various maxlengths. looking for a little more generic way.

Comment: Then grab the `maxlength` attribute value and put it in as the second parameter to slice. There's a bit of duplication, but that's because JS does not have to obey the value length restriction, you need to put it in explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

one way to get this is ... removing all charaters after 5th character. using `substring()`

```
 <input type="button" id="add" />
```

**JS**

```
 $('#add').click(function(){
   var str=$('#fillingInput').val();
   if(str.length > 5) {
      str = str.substring(0,5);

  }
   $('#filledInput').val(str);
 });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wjfH/) ..

it is recommended not to use inline javascript.

Comment: for single element its ok. if i am having 100s of filledInputs with various maxlengths, this seems little costly for me.

Comment: hmmm... ya .. in that sace you need to create a function and call that function instead.. though this doesn't reduce your work.. are you using jquery validator to validate ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#add').click(function () {
    var str = $('#fillingInput').val();
    if (str.length > 5) {
        str = str.substring(0, 5);
        $('#filledInput').val(str);
    }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jQuery you can add a "valHook" which hooks into each call of .val()

```
$.valHooks.input = {
    set: function(element, value) {
        if ("maxLength" in element && value.length > element.maxLength)
            value = value.substr(0, element.maxLength);
        element.value = value;
        return true;
    }
};
```